# How to use Mina with slf4j on Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, gradle, slf4j, mina

I am getting a DEX error (already added classes..) since mina is depending on slf4j-api, and slf4j-android is also carrying some of the slf4j-api internally.
Is there a way to solve this while still using gradle external (maven based) dependencies?

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.7')
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer seems to be the ability to exclude a module (sub-dependency):

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.7') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also exclude a dependency from one or more configurations, which can be more reliable. E.g. `configurations.all*.exclude module: 'slf4j-api'`.

Comment: I put lines into gradle file, and get an build error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;`